# PHP Email - Should be built in the headers or in the body? (what's more correct)

Tags: php, email, mime, email-attachments

As I'm working on building and sending email in PHP I've noticed that sometimes people put the code for the message and file attachment in the headers and sometimes in the body. They both work. So what's more correct, or does it make a difference?

Here's example code: In the headers

```
if (is_uploaded_file($attachment)) {
  $file = fopen($attachment, 'rb');
  $data = fread($file, filesize($attachment));
  fclose($file);

  $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
  $uid = md5(uniqueid(time()));

  $headers = "From: $from\r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"{$uid}\"\r\n\r\n";

  $headers .= "--{$uid}\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n\r\n";
  $headers .= $message. "\r\n\r\n";

  $headers .= "--{$uid}\r\n";
  $headers .= Content-Type: {$att_type}; name=\"{$att_type}\"\r\n";
  $headers .= Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
  $headers .= Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$att_name}\"\r\n\r\n";
  $headers .= $data . "\r\n\r\n";
  $headers .= "--{$uid}--\r\n";
}
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Same code in the message (body):

```
if (is_uploaded_file($attachment)) {
  $file = fopen($attachment, 'rb');
  $data = fread($file, filesize($attachment));
  fclose($file);

  $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
  $uid = md5(uniqueid(time()));

  $headers = "From: $from\r\n";
  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"{$uid}\"\r\n\r\n";

  $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
  $message .= "--{$uid}\r\n";
  $message .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n\r\n";
  $message .= $msg. "\r\n\r\n";

  $message .= "\r\n--{$uid}\r\n";
  $message .= Content-Type: {$att_type}; name=\"{$att_type}\"\r\n";
  $message .= Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
  $message .= Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$att_name}\"\r\n\r\n";
  $message .= $data . "\r\n";
  $message .= "--{$uid}--\r\n";
}
  mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Assuming both of these work, is one method better than the other? When or why does it matter, or does it matter? I can't seem to find an answer to this.

Comment: Well, if you want to be absolutely correct you'd be using something like the pear mail package instead of mail(). mail() is a simple function that is meant for simple mail.

Comment: Not an expert, but I should think the second one is better, since you can put in a message that is understood by mail clients that don't understand MIME (e.g. "click here (link) to see this message in your browser"). However, MIME is so ubiquitous now, I don't know if there is a practical reason for doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be in the body - [as per the spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2045.txt).

Comment: I didn't find it when I read through that long text but it probably is there.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter; the header and message are ultimately just concatenated to each other.  That said, by definition the headers of an email end at the first empty line.  So, it's probably safer going forward to put the attachment in `$message`, just in case `mail()` ever starts stripping extra line breaks from headers.

Comment: If you've got extra line breaks in your headers then the subsequent headers will be interpreted as part of the body. As per answer elsewhere the spec says that "body parts" should not be in the headers.